# Enable system.columns for Log Engine

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way to fetch the table or column size for tables created with a Log Engine in Clickhouse? I know that MergeTree Engine columns' size info can be queried with the `system.columns` table. But for Log engine, it returns 0 for `data_compressed_bytes` and `data_uncompressed_bytes`:

```sh
┌─database─┬─table──────────────────────────────────┬─name───────────┬─type─────────────┬─default_kind─┬─default_expression─┬─data_compressed_bytes─┬─data_uncompressed_bytes─┬─marks_bytes─┬─comment─┬─is_in_partition_key─┬─is_in_sorting_key─┬─is_in_primary_key─┬─is_in_sampling_key─┬─compression_codec─┐
│ default  │ table_321895094fb2431cad3cc27ca070ec86 │ Related Change │ Nullable(String) │              │                    │                     0 │                       0 │           0 │         │                   0 │                 0 │                 0 │                  0 │                   │
│ default  │ table_4a02605b096f47a381288279891a6aa9 │ Related Change │ Nullable(String) │              │                    │                     0 │                       0 │           0 │         │                   0 │                 0 │                 0 │                  0 │                   │
│ default  │ table_ef618f6114f646759225ffa6cd4d330b │ Related Change │ Nullable(String) │              │                    │                     0 │                       0 │           0 │         │                   0 │                 0 │                 0 │                  0 │                   │
└──────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find a configuration for enabling this for the Log engine. And if it's not possible, what would be a rough estimation given the count and column types? Or would it be too off to attempt that since Clickhouse compresses the data?

Answer (score 2):

It needs to look at the table data in the file system:

1. find out the location of table files

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.tables
WHERE name = '{table name}'
FORMAT Vertical

/* Result:
Row 1:
──────
..
data_paths:                 ['/var/lib/clickhouse/data/test/log_engine_001/']
..
*/
```

2. list all files in this directory

```sh
sudo ls -lsh /var/lib/clickhouse/data/test/log_engine_001

# Result:
# total 88K
# 4.0K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse  64 Feb  3 20:28 __marks.mrk
#  40K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse 40K Feb  3 20:28 id.bin
#  40K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse 40K Feb  3 20:28 name.bin
# 4.0K -rw-r----- 1 clickhouse clickhouse 100 Feb  3 20:28 sizes.json
```

Comment: I kinda suspected this answer :( And this means that if I'm running clickhouse on a  docker container, I need to implement an additional service alongside the http client to fetch this info. Would be a lot nicer if I'd be able to query this with the http client. Thank you very much for the answer though :)

Comment: it was created issue https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/9001